# Starting and Ending Screens in XNA

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

This is my first program in XNA, so apologies if I've missed something obvious. I first attempted to implement loading and ending screens via case logic, and when that didn't work, I wondered if I'd screwed it up somewhere, so I switched to if/else statements.

My result thus far is that no matter what I change my game loads the InGame logic. No start screen, no end screen, no Cornflower Blue versus my InGame Bisque. I have no idea why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace FeedMe
{
    public enum GameState
    {
        Start,
        InGame,
        GameOver
    }

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D kitty;
        Texture2D cheese;
        Vector2 kittyPosition;
        Vector2 cheesePosition = Vector2.Zero;
        float speed1 = 4f;
        float speed2 = 5f;
        float secs = 30000.0f;
        MouseState prevMouseState;
        bool wasDown;
        int clicks;
        int speedUp = 5;
        AudioEngine audioEngine;
        WaveBank waveBank;
        SoundBank soundBank;
        Cue trackCue;
        SpriteFont splashFont;
        GameState currentGameState = new GameState();

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        public Random rnd { get; private set; }

        protected bool Collide()
        {
            Rectangle kittyRect = new Rectangle(
                (int)kittyPosition.X,
                (int)kittyPosition.Y, 
                kitty.Width, 
                kitty.Height
            );

            Rectangle cheeseRect = new Rectangle(
                (int)cheesePosition.X,
                (int)cheesePosition.Y, 
                cheese.Width, 
                cheese.Height
            );

            return kittyRect.Intersects(cheeseRect);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            currentGameState = GameState.Start;
            kittyPosition = Vector2.Zero;
            wasDown = false;
            clicks = 0;
            this.IsMouseVisible = false;
            rnd = new Random();
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            kitty = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/kitty");
            cheese = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/cheese");
            audioEngine = new AudioEngine(@"Content\Audio\GameAudio.xgs");
            waveBank = new WaveBank(audioEngine, @"Content\Audio\Wave Bank.xwb");
            soundBank = new SoundBank(audioEngine, @"Content\Audio\Sound Bank.xsb");
            splashFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Fonts\Splash");
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (currentGameState == GameState.Start)
                soundBank.PlayCue("gameStart");

            if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length > 0)
            {
                currentGameState = GameState.InGame;
            }
            else if (currentGameState == GameState.InGame)
            {
                kittyPosition.X += speed1;

                if (kittyPosition.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - kitty.Width || kittyPosition.X < 0)
                    speed1 *= -1;

                kittyPosition.Y += speed2;

                if (kittyPosition.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - kitty.Height || kittyPosition.Y < 0)
                    speed2 *= -1;

                MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

                if (mouseState.X != prevMouseState.X || mouseState.Y != prevMouseState.Y)
                    cheesePosition = new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);

                if (cheesePosition.X < 0)
                    cheesePosition.X = 0;
                if (cheesePosition.Y < 0)
                    cheesePosition.Y = 0;
                if (cheesePosition.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - cheese.Width)
                    cheesePosition.X = Window.ClientBounds.Width - cheese.Width;
                if (cheesePosition.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - cheese.Height)
                    cheesePosition.Y = Window.ClientBounds.Height - cheese.Height;

                secs -= (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

                if (secs <= 0.0f)
                {
                    secs = 0;
                }

                ButtonState bs = mouseState.LeftButton;
                bool nowDown = bs == ButtonState.Pressed;

                if (Collide() && (!nowDown && wasDown))
                {
                    soundBank.PlayCue("chomp");
                    clicks++;
                    Window.Title = "Cheeseburgers fed = " + clicks + "     Time Remaining = " + (int)secs / 1000;
                    kittyPosition = new Vector2(
                        (rnd.Next(0, Window.ClientBounds.Width - kitty.Width)),
                        (rnd.Next(0, Window.ClientBounds.Height - kitty.Height))
                    );
                }

                wasDown = nowDown;

                if (clicks == speedUp)
                {
                    soundBank.PlayCue("turbo");
                    speedUp = speedUp + 5;
                    speed1 = speed1 * 1.5f;
                    speed2 = speed2 * 1.5f;
                }
            }
            else if (currentGameState == GameState.GameOver)
            {
                soundBank.PlayCue("gameOver");

                if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length > 0)
                {
                    currentGameState = GameState.InGame;
                }
            }

            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            audioEngine.Update();
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if(currentGameState == GameState.Start)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                string text = "Testing!";
                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    splashFont, 
                    text, 
                    new Vector2((Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).X / 2), 
                    (Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).Y / 2)), 
                    Color.DarkBlue
                );

                text = "Testing2!";

                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    splashFont, 
                    text, 
                    new Vector2((Window.ClientBounds.Width/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).X/2),        
                    (Window.ClientBounds.Height/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).Y/2) + 30), 
                    Color.DarkBlue
                );

                spriteBatch.End();
            }
            else if(currentGameState == GameState.InGame)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Bisque);

                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(kitty, kittyPosition, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                spriteBatch.Draw(cheese, cheesePosition, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }
            else if (currentGameState == GameState.GameOver)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                string text = "Testing3";
                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    splashFont, 
                    text, 
                    new Vector2((Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).X / 2), 
                    (Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).Y / 2)), 
                    Color.DarkBlue
                );

                text = "Testing4";

                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    splashFont, 
                    text, 
                    new Vector2((Window.ClientBounds.Width/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).X/2, 
                    (Window.ClientBounds.Height/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).Y/2) + 30), 
                    Color.DarkBlue
                );

                spriteBatch.End();
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing out the value of Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length when you change states from start/gameover to ingame ?

Comment: [link](http://25.media.tumblr.com/565e98c2e7338ddac1fe95ec4f3e7e65/tumblr_mgxczksmJt1qjf83bo1_500.png)  The game in action here. :D  The screens are the only thing I need to get working.

Comment: This is my first program in XNA.  Not sure how to do that.  Tried a few spots with 'Console.WriteLine("This will be displayed in the console window.");' but nothing showed up in the console.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (currentGameState == GameState.Start)
{
                soundBank.PlayCue("gameStart");
                if(Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length>0)
                {
                    currentGameState = GameState.InGame;
                } 
}
```

Without the `{ }` after `if (currentGameState == GameState.Start)` it will only provide the `if` for the next statement, so it will NOT include the`if(Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length>0)`

If you take a closer look on what triggers it,

```
 if(Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length>0)
                {
                    currentGameState = GameState.InGame;
                }
            else if (currentGameState == GameState.InGame)
```

Basicly, it says if no keys are down, go to ingame. Just add the {} around your GameState.Start logic and it should be fine.

Also line 234 Needs to be `new Vector2((Window.ClientBounds.Width/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).X/2), (Window.ClientBounds.Height/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).Y/2) + 30), Color.DarkBlue);`

**EDIT:** You did the same thing with  `else if (currentGameState == GameState.GameOver)` add what I said above for it too.

Comment: Edited it to read: 'if (currentGameState == GameState.Start)
            {
                soundBank.PlayCue("gameStart");
                if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length > 0)
                {
                    currentGameState = GameState.InGame;
                }
            }'  Still not working.

Comment: "Basicly, it says if no keys are down, go to ingame." Are you sure? It actually says, if no keys are down *and* `currentGameState == GameState.InGame` go to ingame. But `currentGameState` is set to `GameState.Start` in the Initialize method. So it should jump the whole block *until* a key is pressed and the game state is set to InGame.

Comment: Thats the point, With my code it acts how you described. In the original code it dosen't.

Comment: Hi Lucius.  I'm still a bit confused, since GetPressedKeys().Length > 0 should imply that once any number of keys are pressed, it should change the game state to InGame?

Comment: Katie, I realize you also need to do the same for `else if (currentGameState == GameState.GameOver)` Add the  { }

Comment: Did that- it still goes straight to the InGame logic.

Comment: double checking all my brackets now just in case. XD

Comment: Triple-checked all my brackets.  It's not that.

Comment: I checked the build output- it's throwing these errors:  C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FeedMe\FeedMe\FeedMe\Game1.cs(215,141): error CS1026: ) expected
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FeedMe\FeedMe\FeedMe\Game1.cs(234,141): error CS1026: ) expected

Comment: Should be this  new Vector2((Window.ClientBounds.Width/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).X/2), 
                    (Window.ClientBounds.Height/2) - (splashFont.MeasureString(text).Y/2) + 30), 
                    Color.DarkBlue);

Comment: I made a project with your code, it works absolutely fine (After fixing the Vector2 error above) Are you sure its building correctly?